# Arguments imply differing number of rows only when knitting

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called 'data' that looks like this:
[image]

It has 428,033 rows.

I am trying to extract the rows with 'Sensor' value of 'Melbourne Central', So I do this:

```
df_melbourne_central = data[data$Sensor == 'Melbourne Central',]
sensor = df_melbourne_central$Sensor
week = df_melbourne_central$Week
count = df_melbourne_central$Count
df_melbourne_central = data.frame(sensor=sensor, week=week, count=count)
```

Running this gives me exactly what I want. A dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

This works perfectly when I run the chunks individually, however when I try knit, it gives the error saying 'Arguments imply differing number of rows'
I checked the length of all the columns and they all have the same length of 6048 rows and no null values.
I am new to R so I am not sure what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the cache option set to FALSE?

Comment: @sashahafner I've tried both TRUE and FALSE. Same error.

Comment: Is it set to FALSE globally or in the chunk? You can try global if you haven't already.

Comment: Also note that you can do your subsetting operation more simply. Here are two options: `df_melbourne_central <- data[data$Sensor == 'Melbourne Central', c('sensor', 'week', 'count')]` or `df_melbourne_central <- subset(data, Sensor == 'Melbourne Central', select = c('sensor', 'week', 'count'))`.

Comment: @sashahafner If run this individually , it works but knitting gives the following error : undefined columns selected.

Comment: @sashahafner Also, i've tried setting cache = TRUE and FALSE globally as well.

Comment: This issue is most likely due to having conflicting objects in your global environment and inside the run call.
If you run the markdown file in a fresh session, it should be fine.
This is due to some scooping rules. R will look for an object in the global environment first, and then in the rmarkdown call environment. If you have an intermediate object in the Global env, youo could run into problems.